# How to add custom buttons to keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard

I would like to have a numeric keyboard so I used `android:inputType="phone"`.

But I do not need **(,),+,*,#,$**  symbols. I would like to be able to use capital **N** instead. So, I need a keyboard with 0-9 and N.

Comment: just a little out of track..can we add a user defined button on the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you cant make custom keyboard layout because the layouts are part of the InputMethod application installed by the user.

You can however [disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) the default keyboard poping-up and build your own custom '[drawer action](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-sliding-drawer-tutorial)' layout which will have keys on it and have the same function of a keyboard while actually its just a UI element which you implement.